# Identify button from script?

Tags: unity, gui

I want from my script to change the color of the button that identify from the Function OnClick. It's possible ?

```
public float Money;
public GameObject[] upgrade_health_level;
public int[] Player1_heal;

void Start()
{
    Money = 60;
    Player1_heal = new int[6];

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{


} // END UPDATE


public void upgrade_HEAL() // button OnClick
{

        if (Player1_heal[0] == 0 && Money >= 10)
        {
            Money -= 10;
            Player1_heal[0]++;
            upgrade_health_level[0].transform.localPosition = new Vector3(10, 0, 0);
        }
        else if (Player1_heal[0] == 1 && Money >= 10)
        {
            Money -= 10;
            Player1_heal[0]++;
            upgrade_health_level[0].transform.localPosition = new Vector3(20, 0, 0);
            // Change the button color that use this function
        }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Sure. Two options.

1. Pass the button as a parameter to the method. You can do this by adding `Button b` as a parameter, telling the method in the inspector (which is how I assuming its wired up already), and then dragging the button into the new parameter field that shows up.
2. Doing everything through code instead.

   ```
   Button btn = SomeGo.GetComponent<Button>();
   btn.onClick.AddEventListener(delegate () {
       //code here
       //btn is accessible
   })
   ```